# Calculating Largest File With Unix Addressing

Tags: unix, memory-management, memory-address

I am trying to work out the largest size file I could allocate using the UNIX addressing 
method if each block is 4K and can hold 1K block addresses.

I can't seem to find any algorithms online to show me how this is calculated.
I assume a 4K block can hold 4 (four) 1K block addresses?

I want to be able to find out the largest file I can allocate using different blocks and block addresses sizes.